# How can I modify the IMDB movie ranking formula.

Tags: average, sorting

For a project, I'm working on films.
I'm trying to establish a ranking of the best actor/director duos.
So, I took inspiration from the formula used by IMDb to rank films:

this is the imdb formula: $(v/(v+m))*R + (m/(v+m))*C$

where:

-v is the number of votes garnered by the movie

-m is the minimum number of votes required for the movie to be in the chart

-R is the mean rating of the movie

-C is the mean rating of all the movies in the dataset

because i want to rate duos and not just one movie, i have to take into account the number of movies the duo realized together.

so this is what I simply did:

$(v/(v+m))*R + (m/(v+m))*C+0.1*n$

where n is the number of movies realized by the duo.

However, I'm not satisfied with the result.

How could I improve this formula?

Comment: You need to explain what is unsatisfactory about the results and what it would mean to improve the formula.  After all, there is some (non-mathematical) issue of practical interpretation behind your decision that the results are unsatisfying, and you don't say what that issue is.  How could anyone possibly help without knowing what you don't like about the results of the formula?